# i deleted my sim an i know wont reinstall whatsapp how do i keep my old number

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I bought a new phone an I want to transfer my old whatsapp number to my new phone but i dont anymore have that sim card it has been deleted is there any way I can still keep my number?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Whatsapp requires a mobile device with a phone number.   The idea being that your phone number becomes your Whatsapp account id.  Should your phone number change, you get a new account.  Just like if someone needs to call you up,  if someone needs to message you on Whatsapp, they'll need your new phone number.

If, after getting a new cellphone account or switching carriers, you want to retain your Whatsapp account,  you'll need to have ported your phone number through your new wireless carrier.  Although, in some countries, you're entitled to a port, depending on the place, you may have to hefty pay fees, wait varying amounts of time or just be unable to port your number.

In all cases, though, you'll need to arrange the port *prior to* canceling the old number.

When you think of it,  not much is associated with your account.   It's just:

- Undelivered messages.
- Your status message.
- A bunch of info you don't have access to that the company's no doubt selling to advertisers :-)
- Your pending balance, if you paid for the service.

If your concern is your balance,  you may want to contact Whatsapp directly on this. They may have a way to transfer this to a new number.